# Kubuntu - 19.10 - Suspends instead of shutting down when closing lid immediately after chosing "Shut down"

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, shutdown, laptop

I'm a bit new to Kubuntu (I used other distros but this one only once) and KDE.

I'm having a little problem when shutting down my laptop: when I select "Shut down" in the "Leave" menu and I immediately close the lid of my laptop it suspends instead of shutting down. And if I open the lid it is shows the lock screen for a few seconds and shuts down.

I have checked every setting about suspending when closing the lid and everything. I don't know if I'm missing some setting or it is a problem or a bug.

I used Ubuntu GNOME but I never had this problem with it, I did this with the same laptop but in Ubuntu it shuts down correctly

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu 19.10, in the "Energy Savings" setup, there are three places where you can set the machine to suspend when the lid is closed (because there are three tabs: on AC, on battery, and on low battery). You have to check all three.

[image]

Comment: I have checked, and I have the "Buttons events handling" option unchecked for the three tabs, the only option I have enabled, related to suspending, is "Suspend session" and it is set to "After 10 minutes"